# Weekly Question of The Week Submissions: Place a Link to the Blog in the Question?

Tags: discussion, blog

The weekly question that requests nominations and voting for "Question of The Week" stresses that the top question will be the subject of a blog post.

Some references to the blog that are contained in the weekly question:

> ...scheduled for publishing to the Security Stack Exchange Blog...
>
> Also, have a look at the blog to check it hasn't already been written
> about.
>
> When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in
> writing about it for the blog.
> This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about...
>
> Note to the answerers, if you dig a question, you can always submit a draft blog post about it, even if its not picked as QotW.

These quotes were taken from https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/798/3488.

Either turning the references to the blog into a link or adding a sentence that specifically gives the address of the blog would seem to be a useful addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good call - although we do have a link to the blog at the bottom of every page, I will make sure we do this going forwards.

Comment: There was a discussion about the link at the bottom of the pages pointing to stackexchange.com here: http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/446/3488. It's tagged as completed, but it takes me to http://blog.stackexchange.com. I think it's supposed to redirect to the security blog, but for me it doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm - okay. I know we get a live blog link at the top when a new post goes up. But that question you linked to states that it should work from the link at the bottom - and it doesn't at the moment.

Comment: Solution found - it turns out that expected behaviour is that the main site links to our blog, but the meta site blog link goes to blogoverlow.com